# If-condition in linq query (fetching from multiple databases)

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework

So I have these three tables:

**Date:**

```
int Id
DateTime RunDate
int ArticleId
```

**Article:**

```
int Id
int Barcode
String Name
int Days
int GroupNumber
```

**Group:**

```
int Id
int Number
String Name
int Days
```

What I want get is all the entries of `Article` and `Date.RunDate` where the `Date.RunDate` minus `Article.Days` is less than `DateTime.Now`. However `Article.Days` may be empty and if it is empty it must fetch `Group.Days` where `Article.GroupNumber` and `Group.Number`matches (`Group.Number` is unique).

My current query only uses the Article.Days:

```
var query = from dates in dbdate.Dates 
            join article in dbarticle.Articles on dates.ArticleBarcode equals article.Barcode
            where dates.RunDate.Subtract(new TimeSpan(article.Days, 0, 0, 0)) > DateTime.Now
            select article;
```

Comment: What type of LINQ? (to-sql, to-entities, ...)

Comment: @GertArnold it is to-entities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `DbFunctions.AddDays`. Then you can use the `??` null coalescing operator to get to the right number of days to subtract.

```
var query = from date in dbdate.Dates 
            join article in dbarticle.Articles on date.ArticleBarcode
                                               equals article.Barcode
            let days = article.days 
                    ?? db.Groups.Where(g => g.Number == article.GroupNumber)
                                .Select(g => g.Days).FirstOrdefault()
                    ?? 0
            where DbFunctions.AddDays(date.RunDate, days * -1) > DateTime.Now
            select article;
```